# King move to other side

Tags: endgame, rules

During a game of chess, after several moves. Is it an automatic win as soon as you get your king all the way across the board?

I was told this is a tournament rule.

Comment: They were definitely fooling you! Maybe your opponent was lost but somehow managed to reach the 8th rank with the king?

Comment: I hope this did not happen during a tournament game.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not a rule in chess. There are plenty of games where one king reaches its 8th rank, and the game continues, with all three results still possible. Here are the [Fide rules](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article)

Answer (score 5):

As @Evargalo noted in their answer, that is not part of the official rules of chess. However, [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/) hosts a chess variant called "Racing Kings" in which your mentioned rule holds true.